# What makes a question active?

Tags: support

Answering a question marks it as active, but are there any other actions that can do that (i.e. voting, commenting, flagging, reporting, etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this FAQ post on Meta Stack Overflow: [What can cause my question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)

> The following will cause a question to be bumped:
>
> - Addition of an answer
> - Edit or retag of the question, or edit of an answer[...]
> - Addition of a bounty (by anyone)
> - [Successful reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129185/when-a-question-gets-reopened-it-should-get-a-bump/129198#129198)
>     (if the question was closed)
> - The Community user will bump unanswered questions every hour. The number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site [...]

(The re-open bump is a fairly recent development, or rather an old one that was recently fixed.)

Comment: Bounties don't bump. (or at least, mine didn't a few weeks ago on a months old question, so I edited it.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz They do. (Example: [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113397/add-a-delete-tab-to-the-new-review-section); last activity date 1 second after a bounty was placed.) Maybe there are some special rules, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz When in doubt, blame caching for things not looking like they've updated.